# Get Kruskal-Wallis Ranks from function

Tags: python, anova, kruskal-wallis

I'm using Kruskal-Wallis to do some analysis on non-normal/heterskedastic data and I'm keen to use Welch's t-test implementation data as described by Cribbie et al [here](https://digitalcommons.wayne.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1129&context=jmasm).  Their process involves performing the Welch's T-test on the ranks from K-W.

The Python part of the question is: is there a way to save and recall the ranked values from the K-W test?  I'm using the K-W implementation stats.kruskal and I don't see much info in the API.  Is there an alternate implementation that would give me what I'm after?

Thanks in advance.